# Trailing end-of-lines in C++ with Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, newline, end-of-line

I'm new to a team that uses SVN for source control.  I'm used to Git myself, so I'm really at a loss with all of SVN's pre-commit/post-checkout filters for tracked files.

I've commited some C++ source code with standard-compliant trailing end-of-lines using TortoiseSVN (on Windows).  One colleague, also on Windows and using TortoiseSVN GUI client sees the same files as I committed: they have trailing `\n`.  Another uses the `svn` command-line client on Linux and sees files with no trailing `\n`.

Looking at the files using the web-based Visual SVN server source code browser, we can see that the committed source files do *not* contain the trailing `\n`.  This makes me think the problem is on the client side of both TortoiseSVN users.  Also, if I commit a file with *two* trailing `\n` characters, only one of them is removed.

**Question:** how do I disable this behavior, so that source files are modified *exactly* as I committed them?  All my editors are configured to produce UTF-8 encoded text, spaces-only (no tabs) with Unix line-endings and add the trailing `\n` automatically.  I'd like this to be committed *as is*.

Comment: Related question: how do I ensure what I see is exactly what's on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [svn:eol-style](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.5) property and the [auto-props](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2) section in the config file.